# Symfony2 add event listener dynamically

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

How would you add an event listener (in my case it's a doctrine event) dynamically to the kernel without using services.yml pattern?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer myself after doing some digging into the vendor directory and `appProdProjectContainer.php` file. If you want your events to be registered with event manager you have to specify the tags in your `services.yml` for the events that you want this to trigger for like:

```
  event_listener:
      class: Company\MyBundle\Listener\MyListener
      arguments: [@security.context, @logger]
      tags:
          -   
              name: doctrine.event_listener
              event: preRemove
          -   
              name: doctrine.event_listener
              event: onFlush
```

Now if you want to dynamically register these events, you need to leave the `event_listener` resource in `services.yml`, but delete the tags part and dynamically add them that as follow:

```
if (something) {
  $evm = $em->getConnection()->getEventManager();
  $evm->addEventListener(
      [
        0 => 'preRemove',
        1 => 'onFlush'
      ],
      $this->container->get('event_listener');
}
```

Comment: is there a similar way to accomplish this with `JMSSerializerBundle`? I'm checking the code and unfortunately this seems to be out of chance

Comment: unfortunately there is no interface to specify priorities when using `$em->getConnection()->getEventManager()->addEventListener(...)`