# Doctrine event subscriber registered only for website

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

In my Symfony project I have both a website and several Symfony Commands which run in CLI.

Actually I created a simple Doctrine event subscriber:

```
  doctrine.event_subscriber.web_sync:
      class: WebUiBundle\EventSubscriber\WebSyncSubscriber
      tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
```

All works as expected but the point is I need this subscriber to be called only if an event (postUpdate, postPersist, etc..) comes from website and not from some CLI command.

So actually in every callback I check if request doesn't come from CLI with the following function:

```
function isCli() {
    return (!isset($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']) && (php_sapi_name() == 'cli' || (is_numeric($_SERVER['argc']) && $_SERVER['argc'] > 0)));
}
```

but I wonder if there's a way to directly register and use this subscriber only if Doctrine events come from website (so basically `HttpKernel`).

Any idea?

Comment: Maybe an option could be to use the `kernel.request` event (to define from where was executed script)?

Comment: @Neodan the point is I have no problem to check if request comes from web or cli, I would just avoid Doctrine callbacks if not needed for performance reasons...

Comment: You can try to dynamically add the event listeners (related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31950983/symfony2-add-event-listener-dynamically)